# Як правильно написати прізвище?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання

В мене прізвище Кірко. Все життя, час від часу, виникає питання відмінювання мого прізвища. 
Сьогодні в документі мені написали "Кірку Руслану Ігоровичу"
Таке питання: чи вірно провідмінювали - "Кірку"?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту! Думаю, що відповідь на ваше запитання вже дана (посилання у попередньому коментарі), але у вашому випадку, є дуже наочний спосіб перевірити правопис: просто подивитися, як відмінюють прізвище київського мера Кличка.

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, зазвичай такі прізвища відмінюються: можна сказати «(кому?) Кірку» або «(кому?) Кіркові».